# How to output combined arrays to PDF

Tags: c#, arrays, pdf

I've just learned how to merge two or more arrays into one. The problem that I'm having now is that if I want to output the result to PDF only the very last array is printed, the others are lost. And it doesn't matter which way I'm using to merge arrays. The merging itself seems to be working, I can see it by the size of the combined array, but in PDF only last array is printed. Below is an example. Thank you.

```
//omCol and omGS are the memory streams
    byte[] bytCol = omCol.ToArray();
    byte[] bytGS = omGS.ToArray();       
    byte[] bytDest = bytCol.Concat(bytGS).ToArray();
    MemoryStream omDest = new MemoryStream(bytDest);
    LoadPDF(omDest);

public void LoadPDF(MemoryStream input)
{

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.pdf");
    input.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream); 
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
    Response.End();

}
```

Comment: If you append multiple pdfs to one another like your code does, you don't get a single pdf with the contents of all input documents, the result is no valid pdf anymore.  Pdf readers then may attempt to fix it which may result in only the data from one source being visible.

Comment: Thank you. So what would be a workaround? There are several ways to combine PDF files using, for instance, iTextSharp, but I'm dealing here with streams, not with existing files.

Comment: *"but I'm dealing here with streams, not with existing files."* - That's no problem: Itextsharp and other pdf libraries usually also allow you to read pdfs from stream or at least from byte array, not only from file.